# Label Smoothing in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, transfer-learning

I'm building a `ResNet-18` classification model for the **Stanford Cars** dataset using transfer learning. I would like to implement [label smoothing](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.06548.pdf) to penalize overconfident predictions and improve generalization.

`TensorFlow` has a simple keyword argument in [`CrossEntropyLoss`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/softmax_cross_entropy). Has anyone built a similar function for `PyTorch` that I could plug-and-play with?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The generalization and learning speed of a multi-class neural network can often be significantly improved by using **soft targets** that are a **weighted average** of the **hard targets** and the **uniform distribution** over labels. Smoothing the labels in this way prevents the network from becoming over-confident and label smoothing has been used in many state-of-the-art models, including image classification, language translation, and speech recognition.

---

**Label Smoothing** is already implemented in `Tensorflow` within the cross-entropy loss functions. [BinaryCrossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy), [CategoricalCrossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy). But currently, there is no official implementation of **Label Smoothing** in `PyTorch`. However, there is going an active discussion on it and hopefully, it will be provided with an official package. Here is that discussion thread: [Issue #7455](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7455).

Here We will bring some available best implementation of **Label Smoothing (LS)** from `PyTorch` practitioner. Basically, there are many ways to implement the **LS**. Please refer to this specific discussion on this, one is [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7455#issuecomment-746999397), and [another here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7455#issuecomment-747769787). Here we will bring implementation in **2** unique ways with two versions of each; so total **4**.

### Option 1: CrossEntropyLossWithProbs

In this way, it accepts the `one-hot` target vector. The user must manually smooth their target vector. And it can be done within `with torch.no_grad()` scope, as it temporarily sets all of the `requires_grad` flags to false.

1. [Devin Yang](https://github.com/PistonY): [Source](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7455#issuecomment-513062631)

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.nn.modules.loss import _WeightedLoss


class LabelSmoothingLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, classes, smoothing=0.0, dim=-1, weight = None):
        """if smoothing == 0, it's one-hot method
           if 0 < smoothing < 1, it's smooth method
        """
        super(LabelSmoothingLoss, self).__init__()
        self.confidence = 1.0 - smoothing
        self.smoothing = smoothing
        self.weight = weight
        self.cls = classes
        self.dim = dim

    def forward(self, pred, target):
        assert 0 <= self.smoothing < 1
        pred = pred.log_softmax(dim=self.dim)

        if self.weight is not None:
            pred = pred * self.weight.unsqueeze(0)   

        with torch.no_grad():
            true_dist = torch.zeros_like(pred)
            true_dist.fill_(self.smoothing / (self.cls - 1))
            true_dist.scatter_(1, target.data.unsqueeze(1), self.confidence)
        return torch.mean(torch.sum(-true_dist * pred, dim=self.dim))
```

Additionally, we've added an assertion checkmark on `self. smoothing` and added loss weighting support on this implementation.

2. [Shital Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207661/shital-shah): [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59264908/9215780)

Shital already posted the answer here. Here we're pointing out that this implementation is similar to [Devin Yang](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7455#issuecomment-513062631)'s above implementation. However, here we're mentioning his code with minimizing a bit of `code syntax`.

```
class SmoothCrossEntropyLoss(_WeightedLoss):
    def __init__(self, weight=None, reduction='mean', smoothing=0.0):
        super().__init__(weight=weight, reduction=reduction)
        self.smoothing = smoothing
        self.weight = weight
        self.reduction = reduction

    def k_one_hot(self, targets:torch.Tensor, n_classes:int, smoothing=0.0):
        with torch.no_grad():
            targets = torch.empty(size=(targets.size(0), n_classes),
                                  device=targets.device) \
                                  .fill_(smoothing /(n_classes-1)) \
                                  .scatter_(1, targets.data.unsqueeze(1), 1.-smoothing)
        return targets

    def reduce_loss(self, loss):
        return loss.mean() if self.reduction == 'mean' else loss.sum() \
        if self.reduction == 'sum' else loss

    def forward(self, inputs, targets):
        assert 0 <= self.smoothing < 1

        targets = self.k_one_hot(targets, inputs.size(-1), self.smoothing)
        log_preds = F.log_softmax(inputs, -1)

        if self.weight is not None:
            log_preds = log_preds * self.weight.unsqueeze(0)

        return self.reduce_loss(-(targets * log_preds).sum(dim=-1))
```

Check

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.nn.modules.loss import _WeightedLoss


if __name__=="__main__":
    # 1. Devin Yang
    crit = LabelSmoothingLoss(classes=5, smoothing=0.5)
    predict = torch.FloatTensor([[0, 0.2, 0.7, 0.1, 0],
                                 [0, 0.9, 0.2, 0.2, 1], 
                                 [1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 1]])
    v = crit(Variable(predict),
             Variable(torch.LongTensor([2, 1, 0])))
    print(v)

    # 2. Shital Shah
    crit = SmoothCrossEntropyLoss(smoothing=0.5)
    predict = torch.FloatTensor([[0, 0.2, 0.7, 0.1, 0],
                                 [0, 0.9, 0.2, 0.2, 1], 
                                 [1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 1]])
    v = crit(Variable(predict),
             Variable(torch.LongTensor([2, 1, 0])))
    print(v)

tensor(1.4178)
tensor(1.4178)
```

---

### Option 2: LabelSmoothingCrossEntropyLoss

By this, it accepts the target vector and uses doesn't manually smooth the target vector, rather the built-in module takes care of the label smoothing. It allows us to implement label smoothing in terms of [`F.nll_loss`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/1442a92741d8f39e3d6228af2ed8800cc29ed16f/torch/nn/functional.py#L2429).

(a). [Wangleiofficial](https://github.com/wangleiofficial): [Source](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7455#issuecomment-720100742) - (AFAIK), Original Poster

(b). [Datasaurus](https://www.kaggle.com/anjum48): [Source](https://www.kaggle.com/c/siim-isic-melanoma-classification/discussion/166833#930136)  - Added Weighting Support

Further, we slightly minimize the coding write-up to make it more concise.

```
class LabelSmoothingLoss(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, smoothing: float = 0.1, 
                 reduction="mean", weight=None):
        super(LabelSmoothingLoss, self).__init__()
        self.smoothing   = smoothing
        self.reduction = reduction
        self.weight    = weight

    def reduce_loss(self, loss):
        return loss.mean() if self.reduction == 'mean' else loss.sum() \
         if self.reduction == 'sum' else loss

    def linear_combination(self, x, y):
        return self.smoothing * x + (1 - self.smoothing) * y

    def forward(self, preds, target):
        assert 0 <= self.smoothing < 1

        if self.weight is not None:
            self.weight = self.weight.to(preds.device)

        n = preds.size(-1)
        log_preds = F.log_softmax(preds, dim=-1)
        loss = self.reduce_loss(-log_preds.sum(dim=-1))
        nll = F.nll_loss(
            log_preds, target, reduction=self.reduction, weight=self.weight
        )
        return self.linear_combination(loss / n, nll)
```

2. [NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples): [Source](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples/blob/8d8b21a933fff3defb692e0527fca15532da5dc6/PyTorch/Classification/ConvNets/image_classification/smoothing.py#L18)

```
class LabelSmoothing(nn.Module):
    """NLL loss with label smoothing.
    """
    def __init__(self, smoothing=0.0):
        """Constructor for the LabelSmoothing module.
        :param smoothing: label smoothing factor
        """
        super(LabelSmoothing, self).__init__()
        self.confidence = 1.0 - smoothing
        self.smoothing = smoothing

    def forward(self, x, target):
        logprobs = torch.nn.functional.log_softmax(x, dim=-1)
        nll_loss = -logprobs.gather(dim=-1, index=target.unsqueeze(1))
        nll_loss = nll_loss.squeeze(1)
        smooth_loss = -logprobs.mean(dim=-1)
        loss = self.confidence * nll_loss + self.smoothing * smooth_loss
        return loss.mean()
```

Check

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    # Wangleiofficial
    crit = LabelSmoothingLoss(smoothing=0.3, reduction="mean")
    predict = torch.FloatTensor([[0, 0.2, 0.7, 0.1, 0],
                                 [0, 0.9, 0.2, 0.2, 1], 
                                 [1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 1]])

    v = crit(Variable(predict),
             Variable(torch.LongTensor([2, 1, 0])))
    print(v)

    # NVIDIA
    crit = LabelSmoothing(smoothing=0.3)
    predict = torch.FloatTensor([[0, 0.2, 0.7, 0.1, 0],
                                 [0, 0.9, 0.2, 0.2, 1], 
                                 [1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 1]])
    v = crit(Variable(predict),
             Variable(torch.LongTensor([2, 1, 0])))
    print(v)

tensor(1.3883)
tensor(1.3883)
```

---

### Update: [Officially Added](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html)

```
torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=None, size_average=None, 
                          ignore_index=- 100, reduce=None, 
                          reduction='mean', label_smoothing=0.0)
```

Answer (score 9):

I've been looking for options that derives from `_Loss` like other loss classes in PyTorch and respects basic parameters such as `reduction`. Unfortunately I can't find straight forward replacement so ended up writing my own. I haven't fully tested this yet, however:

```
import torch
from torch.nn.modules.loss import _WeightedLoss
import torch.nn.functional as F

class SmoothCrossEntropyLoss(_WeightedLoss):
    def __init__(self, weight=None, reduction='mean', smoothing=0.0):
        super().__init__(weight=weight, reduction=reduction)
        self.smoothing = smoothing
        self.weight = weight
        self.reduction = reduction

    @staticmethod
    def _smooth_one_hot(targets:torch.Tensor, n_classes:int, smoothing=0.0):
        assert 0 <= smoothing < 1
        with torch.no_grad():
            targets = torch.empty(size=(targets.size(0), n_classes),
                    device=targets.device) \
                .fill_(smoothing /(n_classes-1)) \
                .scatter_(1, targets.data.unsqueeze(1), 1.-smoothing)
        return targets

    def forward(self, inputs, targets):
        targets = SmoothCrossEntropyLoss._smooth_one_hot(targets, inputs.size(-1),
            self.smoothing)
        lsm = F.log_softmax(inputs, -1)

        if self.weight is not None:
            lsm = lsm * self.weight.unsqueeze(0)

        loss = -(targets * lsm).sum(-1)

        if  self.reduction == 'sum':
            loss = loss.sum()
        elif  self.reduction == 'mean':
            loss = loss.mean()

        return loss
```

Other options:

- [utils.pytorch](https://github.com/eladhoffer/utils.pytorch/blob/master/cross_entropy.py#L70) Implementation
- [DeepMatch](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~sidharth/deepmatcher/_modules/deepmatcher/optim.html) implementation

Answer (score 6):

None that I know of.

Here are two examples of PyTorch implementation:

- [`LabelSmoothingLoss` module](https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-py/blob/e8622eb5c6117269bb3accd8eb6f66282b5e67d9/onmt/utils/loss.py#L186) in OpenNMT framework for machine translation
- [`attention-is-all-you-need-pytorch`](https://github.com/jadore801120/attention-is-all-you-need-pytorch/blob/master/train.py#L38), re-implementation of Google's [Attention is all you need paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762)

Answer (score 4):

From version 1.10.0 Pytorch officially supports label smoothing and soft targets in [`torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html).

Answer (score 1):

**label smoothing PyTorch implementation**
Ref: https://github.com/wangleiofficial/label-smoothing-pytorch

```
import torch.nn.functional as F

def linear_combination(x, y, epsilon):
    return epsilon * x + (1 - epsilon) * y


def reduce_loss(loss, reduction='mean'):
    return loss.mean() if reduction == 'mean' else loss.sum() if reduction == 'sum' else loss


class LabelSmoothingCrossEntropy(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, epsilon: float = 0.1, reduction='mean'):
        super().__init__()
        self.epsilon = epsilon
        self.reduction = reduction

    def forward(self, preds, target):
        n = preds.size()[-1]
        log_preds = F.log_softmax(preds, dim=-1)
        loss = reduce_loss(-log_preds.sum(dim=-1), self.reduction)
        nll = F.nll_loss(log_preds, target, reduction=self.reduction)
        return linear_combination(loss / n, nll, self.epsilon)
```

Answer (score 1):

Be informed that there are 2 different formulations of label smoothing in the literature and online. Let us define a total number of classes as `n`, and a label smoothing hyperparameter as `smoothing`.

1. The canonical formulation from the original paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00567.pdf : the smoothed distribution is a linear combination of a one-hot `target` vector and of a uniform distribution accross `n` classes, such as: `(1 - smoothing) * target + smoothing * 1/n`, or in code:

```
true_dist = torch.zeros_like(pred)
true_dist.scatter_(1, target.data.unsqueeze(1), 1 - self.smoothing)
true_dist += self.smoothing / num_classes
```

2. Another popular formulation, which appears a lot online, uses in-place scattering, which is equivalent to the following linear combination: `smoothing * 1/(n-1) + (1 - smoothing * n/(n-1)) * target`

```
true_dist = torch.zeros_like(pred)
true_dist.fill_(self.smoothing / (num_classes - 1))
true_dist.scatter_(1, target.data.unsqueeze(1), 1 - self.smoothing)
```

The canonical formulation is used in the Pytorch's implementation. It also corresponds to Option 2 in the [Innat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773267/21682573). The second formulation is presented in many open-source implementations including Option 1 in the above mentioned [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773267/21682573).

Answer (score 0):

This currently has no official implementation in PyTorch, but has been proposed both as a high priority [Feature Request #7455](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7455), and separately in TorchVision [Issue #2980](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/2980).

---

There are a number of implementations in other libraries:

- [NJUNMT-pytorch](https://github.com/whr94621/NJUNMT-pytorch/blob/aff968c0da9273dc42eabbb8ac4e459f9195f6e4/src/modules/criterions.py#L131) `NMTCritierion()._smooth_label()`
- [Snorkel](https://snorkel.readthedocs.io/en/master/packages/_autosummary/classification/snorkel.classification.cross_entropy_with_probs.html) `snorkel.classification.cross_entropy_with_probs()`
- [OpenNMT](https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-py/blob/e8622eb5c6117269bb3accd8eb6f66282b5e67d9/onmt/utils/loss.py#L186) `LabelSmoothingLoss()`

As well as a number of unofficial implementations/code snippets:

- [NVIDIA](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples/tree/master/PyTorch/Classification/ConvNets/resnet50v1.5) `ResNet50 v1.5`
- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/cross-entropy-with-one-hot-targets/13580/5

---

[TensorFlow / Keras implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy)
`tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(label_smoothing)`

Answer (score 0):

The current top post isn't entirely correct when weights are passed. Note that the PyTorch documentation specifies that when weights are passed and `reduction='mean'`, the normalization is done accounting for the weights:
[image: normalization when weights are passed]

So the reduction should be

```py
if self.weight is not None:
    redw = 1.0/(true_dist*self.weight.unsqueeze(0)).sum()
else:
    redw = 1.0/prediction.shape[0] # 1/n
        
return torch.sum(redw*torch.sum(-true_dist * pred, dim=self.dim))
```

instead of

```py
return torch.mean(torch.sum(-true_dist * pred, dim=self.dim))
```

In full, with this fix:

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.nn.modules.loss import _WeightedLoss


class LabelSmoothingLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, classes, smoothing=0.0, dim=-1, weight = None):
        """if smoothing == 0, it's one-hot method
           if 0 < smoothing < 1, it's smooth method
        """
        super(LabelSmoothingLoss, self).__init__()
        self.confidence = 1.0 - smoothing
        self.smoothing = smoothing
        self.weight = weight
        self.cls = classes
        self.dim = dim

    def forward(self, pred, target):
        assert 0 <= self.smoothing < 1
        pred = pred.log_softmax(dim=self.dim)

        if self.weight is not None:
            pred = pred * self.weight.unsqueeze(0)   

        with torch.no_grad():
            true_dist = torch.zeros_like(pred)
            true_dist.fill_(self.smoothing / (self.cls - 1))
            true_dist.scatter_(1, target.data.unsqueeze(1), self.confidence)
        if self.weight is not None:
            redw = 1.0/(true_dist*self.weight.unsqueeze(0)).sum()
        else:
            redw = 1.0/prediction.shape[0] # 1/n
        
        return torch.sum(redw*torch.sum(-true_dist * pred, dim=self.dim))
```