# Focal Loss + Label Smoothing

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

I'm trying to implement focal loss with label smoothing, I used this implementation [kornia](https://kornia.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.2/losses.html#torchgeometry.losses.FocalLoss) and tried to plugin the label smoothing based on this implementation with Cross-Entropy [Cross entropy + label smoothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55681502/label-smoothing-in-pytorch) but the loss yielded doesn't make sense.

```
Focal loss + LS (My implementation): Train loss 2.9761913128770314 accuracy 0.40519300987212814
```

```
Focal loss(Kornia implementation): Train loss 0.0602325857395604 accuracy 0.8621959099036829
```